# django not a callable issue

Tags: python, django

Coming across the error below, not really sure what is wrong. There was phone field missing in the modal which I did not notice before I ran the python manage.py migrate. Now when I try to run the server, I get the error below. I did make changes to the modal( added the phone field) and tried running python manage.py migrate. I thought it would re-migrate but no luck. Getting the same error as below.

```
    contacts - models.py: 

    from django.db import models
    from datetime import datetime

    # Create your models here.
    class Contact(models.Model):
        listing  =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
        listing_id = models.IntegerField()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        message = models.TextField(blank=True)
        contact_date = models.DateField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
        user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

contacts - admin.py - 

from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Contact



class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =('id', 'name', 'listing', 'email' 'contact_date')
    list_diplay_links=('id','name')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'listing')
    list_per_page=25

admin.site.register(Contact, ContactAdmin)


Error logs: 

(venv) User-MBP:btre_project user$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapperat 0x110c651e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 425, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'contacts.admin.ContactAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[3]' refers to 'emailcontact_date', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ContactAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'contacts.Contact'.
```

Comment: You missed a comma in the tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a comma between `email` and `contact_date` here:

```
list_display =('id', 'name', 'listing', 'email' 'contact_date')
```

String literals can be concatenated in Python if there are no operators between them, so this is in effect

```
list_display = ('id', 'name', 'listing', 'emailcontact_date')
```

which is what the error message alludes to.

Add the comma, like

```
list_display = ('id', 'name', 'listing', 'email', 'contact_date')
```

and you're off to the races.

(By the way: that `user_id` column should probably be a ForeignKey to `user`, not a raw ID...)